# Image processing problems that can be solved using parallel computing?

Tags: gpu, hpc

Many of the problems in Image processing are embaressingly parallel. But I want to know is it worth solving Image processing using parallel computing? Are there real practical problems in image processing that can benefit form parallel computing? If so what are those? I am not taking about mliticore CPUs, instead I am talking about parallelism offered by GPUs, and clusters of GPUs.

Comment: I guess it depends on the problem, like what kind of algorithm you are using, what specific problem you are solving, or maybe the language you are using. if the processing is explicit of course it can be paralleled easily. the question should be more specific.

Comment: I think this question is too broad for a useful answer, but a short reply would be: Yes, in particular if you want to do real time processing of image sequences. Have a look at some of the things on http://gpu4vision.icg.tugraz.at/.

Comment: Ah! The days using 50+ cores on the University's cluster to calculate the optical flow on 100,000+ images :)  Would have taken 3 months at home...